# Pull request replace files without any asking in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-pull

I used to start with SourceTree as a tool for Git. I am facing one issue. Whenever a pull request is done, it is going to replace files from remote to local. There is no warning/asking message about it. It is kind of resolved automatically. If there is a conflict it prompts me to do it manually, but in some scenarios I would like to see which files will be overwritten. And maybe I would like to choose which file should not be replaced during the PULL request.

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: looks like you do not understudy how git works. `pull` means `fetch` from remote repro and merge remote tracking branch for current branch. So this is not SourceTree issue, just read about `git pull` or just use `git fetch`.

Comment: Ok good, but is it possible to make PULL and be informed about the files that are going to be replaces automatically? Let me read your proposal....